JWT session token expiration changing with Google Provider
I have successfully setup authjs with my Google Provider.
Everything works fine, except for the session maxAge.
I want the session to not last longer than 10 minutes.
For testing purposes I set it to 1 minute.
I restart the server to make sure changes take place (just in case)
When I freshly load a page (root/landing) I can see in the client the authjs token with an expiration of 1 minute in the future:

But as soon as I navigate to another page by clicking around, the session expiration now jumps 1 month! (default expiration value)

Not really sure what is going on but its extremely confusing
Here is my auth.ts in case that helps:
export const { handlers: { GET, POST }, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(client),
  // experimental: {
  //   enableWebAuthn: true,
  // },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? true : false,
  ...authConfig,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 1 * 60, 
    updateAge: 0,
  },
  // jwt: {
  //   maxAge: 1 * 60, // 30 days
  // },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
    error: "/auth/error",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      if (!user || !user.email || !allowedUsers.includes(user.email)) {
        return false
      }
      return true
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token?.sub && session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub
      }
      if (token.plan && session.user) {
        session.user.plan = token.plan as string
      }
      if (token.trial_end && session.user) {
        session.user.trial_end = token.trial_end as Date
      }
      if (!session.user.session_expiry) {
        // set expiration to 12 hours for now
        const exp = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1*60*1000).toISOString();
        session.user.session_expiry = exp;
      }
      return session
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, trigger }) {
      try {
        if (trigger === "signUp" && user?.id && user?.email && user?.name) {
          await copyDefaultCategoriesToUser(user.id);
          await setTrialEndForUser(user.id);
          await sendEmail(user.email, 'welcome', user.name);
        }
        else if (trigger === "signIn" && user?.id) {
          //get account balances for all accounts
          await refreshInstitutionsAccounts(user.id);
          // do the same for manual accounts
          await updateManualAccounts(user.id);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('JWT - Error:', error)
      }
      if (!token.sub) {
        return token
      }

      const dbUser = await getUserById(token.sub)
      if (!dbUser) {
        return token
      }
      token.plan = dbUser.plan
      token.trial_end = dbUser.trial_end
      return token
    }
  }
})

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    accessToken?: string,
    user: {
      plan: string,
      trial_end: Date,
      session_expiry: string
    } & DefaultSession["user"]
  }
}


declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    accessToken?: string
  }
}

UPDATE: I managed to get something to work a bit better:
By modifying the refetchInterval in the SessionProvider I am able to fetch a session-token that is valid for the exact amount of time I setup in the session.maxAge
But if the page remains open, the session never expires.
Will keep updating
